# iPhone was unable to locate for nearly five hours on find My Iphone app on a synced device.

Tags: iphone

How can I find out when my Iphone was turned off, and it's location during the time it was turned off?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.**

- The device reports its location to Find My iPhone when requested, not constantly.
- The device can't send its location if its off.